# make a matrix from rasterLayer / plotting custom coloured raster in ggmap

Tags: raster, r, ggmap

I'm trying to add a raster layer to a ggmap object. The basic data is a .tif and as I get strange errors by loading it by the package `tiff` or `rtiff`, I decided to make first a rasterLayer (it works) and than add it to the map.

The `ggmap() + inset_raster()` works for me, however, I cannot assign custom colours (which are predefined) to the raster layer (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33421191/using-ggmap-with-inset-raster)).

That's why I ended up with `ggimage`, which requires a matrix, array, imagematrix or something which understands `as.raster`.

When I convert my RasterLayer to one of these formats and put it in `ggimage`, I get the error message:

> Error in if (max(mat) > 1 || min(mat) < 0) { :
>
> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

The .tif is quite big (107Mb), which may be the reason why I cannot use `tiff/rtiff` (converting to polygons seems not to work for the same reason), but how could I handle the error of ggimage?

Or do you have maybe a better idea to get the raster into the map?

P.S.: It does not have to be ggmap, but I need to use a dynamic change of layer extent later, which is only possible with `coord_map` without weird displaying (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38853917/avoiding-hoizontal-lines-and-crazy-shapes-when-plotting-maps-in-ggplot2)).